# Android - Improve Layout view hierarchy

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, grid-layout, android-tablayout

I want to have this layout structure:
[image]

I achieved this with many nested LinearLayouts and nested weights, but I can see that this is really bad for performance. Has anyone an idea how to get such an layout?

I should also say, that it should be above the whole screen.

Comment: use GridLayout, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

Comment: How can I achieve with GridLayout that on the left there are 4 Buttons and on the right are 5?

Comment: I think you can use GridLayout for all 4 Buttons Column only, reducing some linearlayout. If you want best performance, you may need to write your own ViewGroup, this is a trade off.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the layout like this using table layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="8" >

    <Button
        android:layout_columnSpan="4"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_columnSpan="4"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="2" />


    <Button
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="3" />


    <Button
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="3" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_rowSpan="5"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="side"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="side"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="side"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="side"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="side"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="3" />


    <Button
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="3" />


    <Button
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="3" />


    <Button
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="3" />


    <Button
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="3" />















</GridLayout>
```

If you have any comment it. I am glad to answer you.

Comment: But with this solution I don't have the 5 Buttons on the right, but 2 Buttons below everything is that right?

Comment: Stay online I give a solution in few minutes

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TEXTVIEW"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:gravity="center"
     />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="TEXTVIEW" />

   <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="40dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```